# What things and objects uses Blood Ability in Graveyard floor?

Tags: kangokutou-mary-skelter

I can't seem to find anything besides Snow Whites blood ability which breaks walls and Sleeping Beauties arrow to shoot the button in Graveyard floor. So I want to know if there's anything else besides there blood ability can be used by other members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graveyard is the second Labyrinth. You don't have all the Blood Maidens when you enter, as such not all the Blood Abilities are required to progress through it...

Characters you should have at this story point:

- Jack - Mary gun (Used in combat to Purge corruption...Later on will gain various buffs, Mary Reverser)
- Alice - Rabbit Hole (Makes a save point and a one way "town portal")
- Red Riding Hood - Scissors (Cuts chains on chests, cuts wall hearts, cuts Bamboo walls)
- Sleeping Beauty - Bow (Triggers buttons, dispatches dangerous plants, puzzle flame arrows)
- Snow White - Explosive (Destroy crumbling walls and topple tree obstacles)
- Thumbelina - Shrink (Shrinks key items or shrinks inventory items to change their stats)

So in the graveyard you should find:

Crumbling walls, Wall hearts, Trigger buttons, Flame arrow puzzle, Dangerous plants, Tree obstacles, and also

> ***Dash (level 5 has a wind wall)*** not required to complete the chapter.

If you select to explore Temple before Downtown, you only get

> Cinderella a chapter later.

But you can revisit any labyrinth, which means you can blither back into them with any of the Blood Maidens as the game progresses, to either complete higher levels or just for farming.

Other Blood Maidens:

> - Cinderella - Dash (Increased Speed, move against wind walls, run over crumbling floors)
>
>  - Kaguya - Bamboo Defense (Protects versus trap damage and 1st hit nightmare damage)
>
>  - Rapunzel - Hair (Reach objects at a distance or grips overhead rails that move)
>
>  - Hameln - Iron Piccolo (Reaches objects at a greater distance, moves iron floor blocks)
>  
>  - Gretel - Bread Crumbs (Short range Teleport)

Graveyard allows access to the following areas as the story progresses:

> City Streets, Tower Base and Downtown

Graveyard can be good for Farming Blood Crystals later on.
A key is required for a locked chest on level 2. By the time you get it, the item is worthless. :o\

If you are part of the Steam community, check out some member guides.

Comment: Sorry I have to remove the statement about your game completion on the answer (congrats, by the way :), but hopefully you can understand that the statement doesn't add any insight to the question, and we try to really focus on the meat of the question and its answer.